# Python FieldStorage Key Value Manipulation

Tags: python, dictionary, cgi

I am making a Python cgi that gets values from a (Extjs) form.

I want to modify the value that the cgi gets from the form and translate it to another one, baed on a translation table.

For example, if the value that I got from the form is 'foo' then I want it to become 'bar', here is what I tried to do :

```
import cgi
import json
import cgitb
print "Content-type: application/unknown\n\n" 

#Create a translation table
fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
#Create a translation table
tr = { 'foo' : 'bar', 
 'original_value' : 'translated_value'
}
#Create new dictionnary to match with the translation table
nfs = {fs[k]:tr[k] for k in fs.keys()}
```

But the problem is that, the fieldStorage items are in this format :

```
{('field_name'),('field_value')}
```

What I want is something like :

```
{'field_name':'field_value'}
```

Otherwise the translation won't work.

Please how can I translate the received field values to make them match the adequate value (=the value of the given key) of the translation table ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `FieldStorage` is _mostly_ like a dictionary. I don't see why you have to convert it.

Comment: Yes but the line `nfs = {fs[k]:tr[k] for k in fs.keys()}` gives me this error : `unhashable type: 'list`

Comment: What does `fs.keys()` print out. Also i don't think you can initialziae dictionary like this

Comment: it prints the field name. `['name']`
How can I correct it please?

Comment: Well your statement returns a `syntax error - Invalid Syntax` for me. If you have to form a dict out of `fs` and `tr` try `dict([(fs[k],tr[k]) for k in fs.keys()])`

Comment: I still get the error `unhashable type: 'list`

Comment: Print `[fs[k] for k in fs.keys()]`

Comment: `[[MiniFieldStorage('f_name', 'value'), MiniFieldStorage('f_name', 'value')]]`

Comment: well you have a `list` in `fs[k]` which you are trying to make as a key in a dict. Lists cannot be the key in a dictionary. hence your problem. Maybe you should change your logic somewhat